# Appropriate way to place sound arguments when reopening a duplicate marked question

Tags: support, feature-request, exact-duplicates, re-open

The  possibility  to reopen a duplicate marked question is a nice feature. This  action is usually based (at  least  I  do  hope  so) upon sound arguments. Is there a way to  *attach* or *combine* these  arguments with the  reopen action?

Comment: There's no way to attach such arguments to the reopen vote itself. But you can leave a comment explaining why you vote the way you do. Or, you can argue/plea/whatever [in the meta thread dedicated to "discussions" about reopenings etc](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio).  Probably the former is to be preferred unless there already is a reopen request related to that question in the thread. Otherwise that will become unduly cluttered.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks for your quick reply. I've already placed a corresponding comment at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408642). The disadvantage I see is, that some may vote against reopening the question by quickly scanning the question without reading the comments.